# How to put continue in side forEach loop in java8

Tags: java, java-8

How to write continue statement inside forEach loop in java 8.

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(10,21,31,40,59,60);
numList.forEach(x->{
    if(x%2==0){
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
});
```

The above code is giving compile time Error saying **Continue outside of loop**

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(10,21,31,40,59,60);
LOOP:numList.forEach(x->{
    if(x%2==0){
        continue LOOP;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
});
```

The above code is giving compile time Error saying **Undefined Label:LOOP**

Comment: A lambda expression is almost equivalent of instance of an anonymous class. Each iteration will call the overridden method in this instance. So if you want to continue, just return the method when condition is met.

Comment: @Sunil Did any of the solution worked for you? Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/336295)

Answer (score 125):

You can use `return`. It won't stop the whole loop, instead, it will just stop the current iteration.

Use it like this:

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(10,21,31,40,59,60);
numList.forEach( x-> {
    if( x%2 == 0) {
        return; // only skips this iteration.
    }
    System.out.println(x);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

I think in this case, the best solution is filter the list before execute the println...

exemple (I didn't test):

```
List<Integer> numList = Arrays.asList(10,21,31,40,59,60);
numList.stream().filter(x-> x%2 != 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Because of Laziness, I think performance difference between `filter` and `return` inside foreach is small. But I prefer `filter` because it's easier to read.